# I want to select same word from database. table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select same words from database like

```
Database Name: username
====================================================
| id | name  | fathername | ip         | datetime  |
| 1  | Ali   | Imran      |192.168.1.1 | 12-12-2015|
| 2  | Asd   | hafiz      |142.150.8.9 | 12-12-2015|
| 3  | Sef   | warya      |100.178.3.7 | 12-12-2015|
| 4  | Qasim | zaheer     |192.168.1.1 | 12-12-2015|
| 5  | Zulfi | Zahid      |192.168.1.1 | 12-12-2015|
| 6  | Jamel | Hasan      |192.168.1.1 | 12-12-2015|
| 7  | Wasif | Junaid     |192.168.1.1 | 12-12-2015|
====================================================
```

when i use counter (Select Count(*) as number From...... ) then result echo is ( 7 ) i wanna to select same ip as one ip. like (ID: 1,4,5,6,7) 5 is same ip i wanna to show this 5 same ip as 1 IP total record-3

Comment: Use something like `Count(DISTINCT ip)` instead of `Count(*)`.

Comment: looks like you're looking for "Group By" operation. try query like this [ SELECT COUNT(*) AS ipCount, ip from yourTable Group By ip ]  to brush up your sql you can follow this [http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_.._GROUP_BY ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `username` GROUP BY `ip`;
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`ip`) FROM `username`;
```

or

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `username` WHERE `ip` IN (SELECT DISTINCT(`ip`) FROM `username`) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `username` GROUP BY `ip`;
```

Is that what you want ? If not, can you put a scema of what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

In sql,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbl` WHERE `ip` = '192.168.1.1'
```

You can also loop through each using php while loop with this query:

```
SELECT DISINCT(`ip`) FROM `tbl`
```